# Java classLoader and getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I'm having trouble understanding how to load a resource in a way that would work both in eclipse and in a jar.

In my project, I have one source file, `src`.
Under that, I created a new package that I import resources (images, audio..) to.
So it's `src/resources` for resources, and `src/com/Mainclass.java`.

Now, as I understand from other answers, .class.getResource();
starts looking in the directory of the class. Except the directory of the class changes when you extract a jar from eclipse.
In other words,

```
MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/img.png")
```

works **only in Eclipse**.

And I'm not even sure why it works, since resources is not in the same path as the main class. I would instead expect ../resources/img.png to work, since we would go from *com.* to *src/*, where resources is.

Still, once I extract as a jar I find inside it, separated:

```
<root of the jar>/com/mainclass.java

<root of the jar>/src/resources
```

And so it doesn't work.

An easier solution would be: How do I find out the exact directory where MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/img.png") is loading from?
I have tried putting /resources/ in every single subfolder and still it won't work.
**IT WILL** work outside of eclipse if the resources folder is in the same folder as the jar, but not inside the jar itself.

Here is my build path:

[image]

I have no external libs, the projects is a Maven Java Project.

Comment: I think that you should read the Maven base documentation. The source/compiled layout  used in your Eclipse mixes Eclipse way (a lot of) and Maven way (a little).

Comment: For global understanding, read it : https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/.

For resource requirement, read it : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resources should be under `src/main/resources`, if they'll be part of the application, or under `src/test/resources`, if they'll be used just for testing and not be part of the final artifact.

Maven copies the resources from `src/main/resources` to `target/classes` and the ones from `src/test/resources` to `target/test-classes`. During testing, the `target/classes` and `target/test-classes are added to the classpath.

So, your code should actually look something like:

```
MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/img.png")
```

Comment: I upvote as fundamentally right but I am not sure that it will solve its problem as I see his Eclipse configuration and his no knowledge of Maven

Comment: @davidxxx, I know what you mean. I believe the contents of the `src/resources` directory should simply be moved under `src/main/resources` and this should sort it out.

Comment: @carlspirng So are you suggesting I move src/resources into src/main/resources, and then change the code to MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/img.png") for every call to a resource? Just to see if I got this correctly